# Transfer function of delayed noise

Tags: fourier-transform

Imagine I have a random variable whose fequency spectrum looks like
\begin{equation}
W(f)=w_0*(2*\pi*f^2)
\end{equation}
where  $w_0$ is some constant. Clearly this frequency spectrum corresponds to some time spectrum, and because the frequency spectrum is not white noise the autocorrelation is not a delta function. Hence there is some correlation between time data, $W(t)$. My question is if I obtain $W(t)$ from the inverse Fourier transform of $W(f)$, what does the frequency spectrum of a new quantity:
\begin{equation}
Y(t)=W(t)-W(t-\tau)
\end{equation}
looks like? i.e. is there an analytic form for $Y(f)$?